# Convergence of a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $X_n$ takes its values in [0,1] and $p$ is a fixed number in $[0,1]$ Now if 
$ X_{n+1} = 1-p+pX_n $ with probability $X_n$ and $X_{n+1} = pX_n$ with probability $1-X_n$ . I know that $X_n$ is a martingale but why it converges almost surely? with which one of the theorems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X_n$ takes its values in $[0,1]$, we have in particular

$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|X_n\|_1=1<\infty$$

Hence $X_n \to X_{\infty}$ almost surely for some random variable $X_\infty$ ($L^1$-bounded martingales are a.s. convergent).

Comment: Thanks and what would be the distribution of the limit?

Comment: Concerning the distribution you can take a look at this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243554/probability-that-a-sequence-of-random-variables-converges-to-0-or-1/243620#243620) (choose $\alpha:=1-p$, $\beta:=p$).